# Action dispatched multiple times in React lifecycle method

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, graphql

I'm developing an application which has the functionality to verify an email when user registers for the application.  When you user registers, a code is generated and a link is sent to the user.  When the user clicks on the link, the frontend checks in with the backend to verify the code.  If the code checks out, then an "activated" flag is toggled in the user database and the user is redirected to the sign in screen.

I'm using `GraphQL` for the database stuff and `Redux` for state management, I have an action which looks like so:

```
export function confirmActiveUser(token) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(activateUserRequest())
        apolloClient.mutate(
            {
                mutation: CONFIRM_EMAIL,
                variables: { token: token }
            }
        ).then((res) => {
            let { error, ok } = res.data.confirmEmail;
            if (ok === true) {
                dispatch(activateUserSuccess())
            } else {
                dispatch(activateUserFailure())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and the activation page component looks like this:

```
// mapStateToPropsFunction
// mapDispatchToPropsFunction
class MyActivationComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.confirmActiveUser(this.props.params.id) // the generated token
    }

    render() {
       <div>
           {this.props.ifIsActivated
              ? // redirect to sign in
              : // do something else
           }
       </div>
    }
}
```

The problem is that, the `confirmActiveUser` action is being dispatched twice (and thus making 2 database calls), which I think is due to the state changed `activateUserRequest` and `activateUserSuccess` causing re-renders.

The verification is suppose to happen when the page (or rather, the component loads), instead of when a button is pressed.  So, I am essentially trying to avoid having to make multiple DB calls.

What is causing these multiple calls, and what is the preferred way of fetching doing the above.

Thank you very much, help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the real use case of what you want to do, probably you are over engineering something that's very simple.

Comment: @Hosar how so?  The user NEEDS to verify the email, and there needs to be some sort of message depending on whether the validation failed or succeeded.  Your comment is very vague, what exactly do you not deem necessary? Conditional rendering based on state? Using lifecycle methods to dispatch actions when a component loads? Using Redux in my application? Dispatching a succeed/failure action? You're right, I may be over engineering, but that doesn't answer the question as to WHY I'm getting multiple calls to `componentDidMount`.  You feel me?

Comment: @user2444217 I dont think there is any problem with the code you have posted here. Could you post container and component entire code.

Comment: @user2444217 if you are callilng "confirmActiveUser" in componentDidMount then it will not be called again on state change. I think either you are calling this method from somewhere else too or somehow your component is mounting again on dom.

Comment: @Prakashsharma After some testing, I noticed that `componentDidMount` gets called twice in production mode, but only once in development mode... That doesn't sound right at all does it?  Sorry if I can't provide more details.

Comment: Yeah it is strange. But i dont think the provided detail is sufficient to find the main cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the action creator is really called twice from `componentDidMount`, then I think you are mounting the component twice (rendered two times or mounted, unmounted, remounted)...